# The type or namespace name 'Internal' does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have a project that I need to make a small change in. But I can't get it to build.

This is the full error:

> Error 175 The type or namespace name 'Internal' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The reference is there. I also added Reporting.Common and .Winforms to see if that helped. it did not. Build, rebuild, clean, reboot, restart, run in admin. None of that works as well.

Is it possible that I have the wrong reference? I pulled this code straight from our repository, and it works on the machine of the person that worked last on it. I don't have access to that though (consultants, he is away with a client), but I do have access to a backup.

### EDIT

This is the using statement that gives the error

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution;
```

Comment: Ask him why is he using `Internal` - it looks like the namespace is undocumented, making the code very fragile.

Comment: I can't find that namespace , can you give us a clue as to which classes from it are being used?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll update the question with the using statement that is giving the error.

Comment: Microsoft uses "Internal" in namespace names that are internal implementation details.  Should contain types that are internal, they are also heavily subject to change.  So this error is entirely expected.  You'd have to dig up the specific version of the assembly that the original programmer used, there have been a bunch of them.  Best to get ahead by commenting this out and deal with whatever next goes wrong.